# No matching operator<< when using postincrement?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The main problem is that when typing `cout<<f1;` alone it worked as well as `f1++;` alone but when attempting to enter `cout<<f1++;` together it shows that error knowing that when making the post increment it is returning a fraction object.

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& output, fraction& fraction1) 
{
    output << "[" << fraction1.num << "/" << fraction1.denom << "]" << endl;
    return output;
}
fraction fraction::operator ++(int)
{
    fraction temp = *this;
    ++(this->num);
    ++(this->denom);
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    fraction f1;
    cout << f1;
    f1++;
    cout << f1++ << endl;  // Results in compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is:  `no operator "<<" matches these operands`

Comment: change `fraction& fraction1` to `const fraction& fraction1` - you cannot bind a temporary object to a non-const reference

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve], including necessary headers but distilled down to the bare minimum? Further, provide the commandline for compiling and the full error you get. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The error message should also specify what the operands are. This might be followed by a list of candidate functions. These are useful parts of your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasoning by analogy, consider this setup:

```
void doSomething(int& x) {
    x = 137;
}

int main() {
    doSomething(42); // Oops!
}
```

This code won’t compile because there’s an error in the indicated line. The function doSomething expects an `int&`, which you can think of as meaning “please give me an actual int variable or int object somewhere that I can change.” But 42 isn’t an int variable - it’s a pure value, hence the error.

Now, suppose you change main to this:

```
int main() {
    int var = 42;
    doSomething(var++); // Oops!
```

The expression `var++` means “increment var, then hand back the value it used to have.” That means that we’re still passing the pure value 42 into the function, and since the function wants objects and not values, this won’t compile.

However, you *can* make this version of main work by changing doSomething to take in a `const int&`:

```
void doSomething(const int& x) {
     // do something other than change x
}
```

This code works just fine due to how C++ defines const references. Unlike a regular reference, which means “I’d like to be able to change this object,” a const reference works fine when you pass in a pure value, since the const bit means “I promise not to actually change anything here.”

Now, look at your code. It’s basically the same idea as what’s shown above: you have a function named `operator<<` whose second parameter is a `fraction&`. That means that you can’t pass in the result of the ++ operator. And the fix is the same - just change the second parameter to use a const reference.

Hope this helps!